# Kafka stream in DATABRICKS increases a lot of data

Tags: scala, azure-devops, databricks, delta-lake

When I perform a Kafka write stream to a table in Databricks, the incoming data doesn't increase the table size significantly, but it results in a much larger increase in the data size on Blob storage.

```
val kafkaBrokers="<BROKERS>"
val kafkaTopic="<TOPIC>"
val kafkaStartingOffset="earliest"
val groupIdPrefix="<PREFIX>"
val format="delta"
val outputMode="update"

import org.apache.spark.sql._
import io.delta.tables._


val deltaTable = DeltaTable.forName("table_name")

def upsertToDelta(microBatchOutputDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) {  
  
  deltaTable.as("dt")
    .merge(
      microBatchOutputDF.as("stream"), 
      "stream.system_device_id = dt.system_device_id and stream.uid_name=dt.uid_name")
     .whenMatched("stream.is_deleted=true").updateExpr(Map("is_deleted" -> "stream.is_deleted",
                                                     "data_date_time" -> "stream.data_date_time",
                                                     "process_time"->"stream.process_time",
                                                     "uninstall_date"->"stream.uninstall_date",
                                                     "application_id"->"stream.application_id"))
    .whenMatched().updateAll()
    .whenNotMatched().insertAll()
    .execute()
    
}


import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val schema = deltaTable.toDF.schema
val confCheckpointLocation="dbfs:/mnt/user/location"

spark.readStream
.format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",kafkaBrokers)
  .option("subscribe", kafkaTopic)
  .option("startingOffsets", kafkaStartingOffset)
  .option("groupIdPrefix",groupIdPrefix)
  .load()
  .select($"offset".alias("offset"), from_json($"value".cast("string"),schema).alias("value"))
  .select($"value.system_device_id".alias("system_device_id"),
          $"value.uid_name".alias("uid_name"),
          struct(col("offset"),col("value")).alias("record")
   ).groupBy("system_device_id","uid_name").agg(max("record").as("record"))
  .select("record.value.*")
  .writeStream
  .format(format)
  .foreachBatch(upsertToDelta _)
  .outputMode(outputMode)
  .option("checkpointLocation",confCheckpointLocation)
  .trigger(Trigger.AvailableNow)
  .start()
```

I expected the size of the data to be the same as the table or slightly larger, but there are differences ranging from 3 to 5 times larger with each run.

Comment: Please review the tags you're choosing. `[azure-devops]` has **nothing** to do with this question.

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing MERGE and not using [Deletion Vectors](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/deletion-vectors.html) (activated with Photon), then existing data that aren't updated are copied again and again.  You need to run `VACUUM` command ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/vacuum.html)) from time to time to get rid of the files with the old data.

Comment: When I run the "vacuum" command, there is no change in the data size in the storage. In a scenario I observed, when the "optimize and merge" command runs automatically, the data size increases.

Comment: Vacuum deletes only files that are older then specific threshold (7 days by default)

Comment: I run vacuum command daily with cron